# Dynamically Call Shopify Product ID With Jquery Checkbox Type Add To Cart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, shopify

*** Solution is at bottom ***
I'm having some trouble with this one.

Here's what I have:

I have a custom upsell on my product page, by custom I mean:

Upsell Checkbox:

```
    <ul class="upsell" style="margin-left:0px; margin-top:5px;">
    <li>
    <label>
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0386/0093/t/15/assets/.jpg?  14998" width="40px" height="40px" > 
     <input type="checkbox" id="chks1"/><span>Product Title <span>$9.99</span>         </span></label>
   </li>
   <li>
   <label>
   <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0386/0093/t/15/assets/.jpg?14998" width="40px" height="40px" > 
      <input type="checkbox" id="chks1"/><span>Product Title <span>$9.99</span>   </span></label>
    </li></ul>
```

And the Jquery:

```
   <script>
   function triggerChange(){
   $('#chks1').trigger("change");
   }
   $('#chks1').change(function() {
   if(this.checked) {


  jQuery.post("/cart/add.js", {  quantity: 1,  id: 262626  });
   } else {

              jQuery.post('/cart/change.js', { quantity: 0, id: 2626262 });
    }
    });


  </script>
```

My problem is its way to manual... I have so many upsells that I literally have to show the above almost 50 times, both the jquery and the checkboxes in a snippet.

So yesterday I tried this:

```
  <ul class="upsell" style="margin-left:0px; margin-top:5px;">
   {% for product in collections.name.products limit:4 %}
   <li{% cycle ' style="clear:both;"', '', '', ' class="last"' %}>
   <label>
   <img src="{{ product.featured_image |  product_img_url: 'thumb' }}">

    <input type="checkbox" id="chks{{ forloop.index }}"><span>{{   product.title }}                        <   span>  {{ product.price | money }}  </span></span>       </label>
    </li> 
  {% endfor %}
   </ul>
  </div>

  <script>
   function triggerChange(){
   $('#chks1').trigger("change");
   }
   $('#chks1').change(function() {
   if(this.checked) {


  jQuery.post("/cart/add.js", {  quantity: 1,  id: 262626  });
   } else {

              jQuery.post('/cart/change.js', { quantity: 0, id: 2626262 });
    }
     });


    </script>
```

This makes it so I only have to include the one, and it automatically generates based on the collection call.

MY PROBLEM:

I am having trouble dynamically producing the ID: `262626` in the Jquery post (which is how the right product gets added)

I can't figure it out.

Is there a way to dynamically call the product/variant ID in this scenario?

******************************SOLUTION*************************

Figured it out -- here's what I came up with:

```
   <ul class="upsell" style="margin-left:0px; margin-top:5px;">

    {% for product in collections.atc-cart-checkbox.products limit:4 %}


   <li{% cycle ' style="clear:both;"', '', '', ' class="last"' %}  >
  <label>
   <img src="{{ product.featured_image |  product_img_url: 'thumb' }}">

   <input type="checkbox"  id="product-{{ product.variants.first.id }}" name="id" value="{{ product.variants.first.id }}" class="product-select-{{ product.id }}"/><span>{{ product.title }} <span class="upsellprice">
 {{ product.price | money }}<span class="was_price"> {% if product.price < product.compare_at_price_min %}
  {{ product.compare_at_price_min | money }}{% endif %}</span></span></span>    </label>
  </li> 

  <script type="text/javascript">

                 $('#product-{{ product.variants.first.id         }}').change(function() {
                   if(this.checked) {
                      jQuery.post("/cart/add.js", {  quantity: 1,  id: {{   product.variants.first.id }} });
                   }
                   else {
                      jQuery.post('/cart/change.js', { quantity: 0, id: {{ product.variants.first.id }} });
                   }
                });
              </script>
        {% endfor %}


    </ul>
```

Works perfectly -- hope that helps anyone.

Comment: are you talking about this `var productID = //something;   jQuery.post('/cart/change.js', { quantity: 0, id: productID });`

Comment: You can answer your own question... see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

Try-
It's work on Product page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var idProduct = $('#ProductSelect-product-template').val();
    console.log(idVar);
});
```